# Windows multiple user keep processes active

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts

I have two users on my Windows 10 machine. When I start my application on User**A** and switch to User**B** my application does not continue to run properly. Not sure if it gets frozen by Windows itself or what else happens. Switching back to User**A** from User**B** makes the application run properly again.

I want my application to be working as User**A** was never switching off to User**B**. Is this possible?

I need to run separate users.

Running a server machine would be OK too. I just need to know if this is possible at all.

Comment: We need to know more about this application. Is it intended to be used in this manner? What exactly is the application's unwanted behavior when you switch to another user?

Comment: @Twisty The application itself is a graphical application which gets recorded over time. It works as intented when my user is active, that's what I've developed it for. The application can only be ran once per user though. Which makes it hard to scale. I will need to atleast run the application 5 times. Any workarounds other than switching users has not helped me so far.

Comment: It would not surprise me that such an application would not work if not running in the active user's session. This had to do with how the application is written (or what it is doing) rather than how Windows behaves. I.e. the solution will be modifying the program, not Windows.

Comment: @Twisty A solution to scaling would be having multiple machines. Surely this can be avoided when one machine is sufficient enough. I don't have any issues with resources, more so with how windows seems to make sure theres more of them left.